# Add rows filled with NA to complete my data

Tags: r

I want to add rows in order to have 5 rows for each year, filled with NAs.

My data set:

```
df <- data.frame( a= c(2001,2001,2001,2001,2003,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004),
                  b= c(2,4,5,7,8,6,2,4,2,1))
```

My desired output:

```
df2 <- data.frame( a= c(2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2002,2002,2002,2002,2002,2003,2003,2003,2003,2003,2004,2004,2004,2004,2004),
                  b= c(2,4,5,7,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,8,NA,NA,NA,NA,6,2,4,2,1) )
```

**EDIT:**

Other years that exist on my data has more than 5 values for each year stay the same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R solution :

```
do.call(rbind,
  by(df,df$a,function(x){
    if(nrow(x)<5)  
      rbind(x,data.frame(a=unique(x$a),b=rep(NA,5-nrow(x))))
    else x
  })
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a huge help